# How to apply IE Fixes for LESS CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, less

My page code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="no-js ie6" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="no-js ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]--><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

<title>BLUE MONDAY-HOMEPAGE</title>

<!--Default style sheet-->
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/blue.less" media="screen" type="text/css"      title="defaultBlue">
<script src="js/less-1.0.21.min.js"></script>
```

Now Practical question is :

```
/*IE hack */
.ie8 .headerPhone
{ width:200px; 
}
```

Above CSS hack working fine for IE8 but without:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

this meta Tag I used in header. As soon as I put that meta tag again this hack stop working.

Is there any solution that both things will work fine together?

Comment: what is the nature of the issues ... have you considered it being just an issue with your css?

Comment: Without a detail about your issue there probably won't be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LESS gets compiled into CSS, so all you have to do is make sure that the compiled CSS will work in Internet Exploder.

If you're using [ie-specific classes](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/), then you can easily create mixins that will target IE, such as:

```
.inline-block() {
    display: inline-block;
    .lt-ie8 & {
        display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks
For this Solution